# Iphone config file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In desktop applications when talking about a config file sometimes it's about letting the end client change some parameters according to his systems - for example entering his system IP or other parameters that can not be hardcoded, and must change by him because the user doesn't want you to know them.

I read about the option to create a `settings.plist` and reaching the value from `NSBundle` but how can the end client change the values in it?

Comment: also, see https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about implementing a [settings bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html). Once you've done that, the user will be able to adjust the values in the main iOS Settings app - there will be a section for your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are many **[Preference control types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)** available. You can use a **Text field**.

The text field type displays a **title** (optional) and an **editable text field**. You can use this type for preferences that require the user to specify a custom string value.

The key for this type is **PSTextFieldSpecifier**.

To retrieve the edited value at run time, use the below code.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *iPAdress = [defaults objectForKey:@"IP address"];
```

Once these all done, Go To your iPad default **Setting App**-> You can view your application name listed under **Apps section**. Tap on it.

[image]
[image]